# How do fix my code so that these 'players' are sorted into the right 'teams'

Tags: java

I am trying to complete a programming task where I load a URL with information on the 2012 NFL team players. I am using a Hashmap (playerIndfo) where the key is 'team' and the values is an arraylist of all the 'PlayerData' (playersInfo). Currently I have written:

```
    if(playerInfo.containsKey(team)) {
            playerInfo.get(team).add(player);
        }
        else {
            playersInfo.add(player);
            playerInfo.put(team, playersInfo);
        }
```

This seems to add every player to every team, proven by if I attempt to print out information for a certain key, every player is listed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `playersInfo` is the list, right? If you only have one instance of that list, you add all players to the same list. And all teams then have that same list of players.

Comment: What I am trying to say: You need to make sure you use a different list for each team.

Comment: Thank you! - that was a dumb thing to do on my part lol

Comment: that's how learning works, we've all been there :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(playerInfo.containsKey(team)) {
        playerInfo.get(team).add(player);
    }
    else {
        List<PlayerData> playersInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        playersInfo.add(player); 
        playerInfo.put(team, playersInfo);
    }
```

Comment: You have misspelled diamond operator.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if, along with the code, it included an explanation of what about the code solves OP's problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same **playersInfo** list for all players. You should create a new one for each team.

```
 if (playerInfo.containsKey(team)) {
     playerInfo.get(team).add(player);
 } else {
     List<Player> playersInfo = new ArrayList<>();
     playersInfo.add(player);
     playerInfo.put(team, playersInfo);
 }
```